# Protecting circuit boards against shock?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly, mechanical-assembly

Our company have been designing and manufacturing custom circuit boards for some 10 years now, and up till now by far the most common reason for board failure has been a mechanical shock - heavier SMD components (like inductors and such) has a tendency to simply break off the boards even with the slightest shock (like device being dropped even a mere feet from the ground).

How is this problem being handled in the mass manufactured equipment (especially devices used in vibration prone environments and vehicles)? I believe that hot-glueing every component in place is not a proper way to do this, right? Is there any epoxy coatings or something like that being done after board is soldered?

Comment: One word: glue.

Comment: @winny  Seriously? How it's calculated, what components requires to be glued in place, and what does not - by mass, or component height, or what?

Comment: Either from experience or do the vibration testing, check what falls off, glue those, retest, done. FEM analysis could work too.

Comment: Oh, ok. I indeed thought that there is some more elegant solution for this issue. Oh, well. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are most welcome! For SMD specific components, there exist underfill and similar products if you can't do it with glue.

Comment: Take a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236457/white-glue-on-circuit-board

Comment: Perfect! Underfill was exactly the keyword what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @winny - the term I was looking for is called "**pcb underfill**" - a special adhesive that can be dispersed under the SMD components to improve mechanical strength. For a larger components RVT silicone (room temperature vulcanization adhesive) is used to secure them to board.

Comment: Give me a moment an I'll write up an answer. :-)